# C++ Api FindFirstChangeNotification код ошибки 2: Не удается найти указанный файл

Tags: c++, winapi

Код функции *main*.

```
        LPCWSTR path = (LPCWSTR)"F:\\Test\\";
        HANDLE hDir;
        hDir = FindFirstChangeNotification((LPCWSTR)"F:\\Test\\", FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
        if (hDir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            //std::cout << "Handle: 0x" << hDir << " " << path;
            ErrorExit(TEXT("Operation"));
        }
```

`ErrorExit(TEXT("Operation"))` - обработчик функции `GetLastError()`, которая выдает ошибку с кодом 2. Хэндл при выводе равен `0xffffffff`.

Во всех примерах первый параметр функции `FindFirstChangeNotification` указан без приведения к `LPCWSTR`.

Но у меня в *VS2015* без приведения ругается именно на это место, говоря о том, что необходим *лонг поинтер*, который я собственно и ставлю.

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Try to write LPCWSTR path = TEXT( "F:\\Test\\" );

Comment: Как вариант - FindFirstChangeNotificationA("F:\\Test\\"...), возможно некорректно к Widechar приводите.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо помогло

Comment: @Mannso Я написал ответ с целью, чтобы вопрос можно было бы отметить как отвеченный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет написать

```
LPCWSTR path = TEXT( "F:\\Test\\" );
```

тем более, что вы уже используете этот макрос в тексте программы.